# TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'int'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on a game but having problems with my code. This is the error, it is quite annoying any help appreciated!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 18, in <module>
    elif choice > randomnumber:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'int'
```

Here's the code

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python3

import random

win = False

randomnumber = random.randint(1,100)

print("I have picked a number between 1 and 100. Try and guess it!")

choice = input("Pick a number")

if choice == randomnumber:
  print("Good!!")
  Win = True
elif choice > randomnumber:
  print("Too high")
elif choice < randomnumber:
  print("Too Low")

if Win == True:
  exit
```

Comment: I believe that your `choice` variable is type 'string' because the `input` function always creates the input as `type=string`. Try to convert it to int and retry your code.

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: @Employee tag says 3.x

Comment: @Alex_P The error message says that `choice` is a function, not a string.

Comment: The error message implies that you have a function named `choice`, and this is replacing the variable containing the user's input.

Comment: Ia there more code in your script that you're not showing?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to convert the user input to an integer for your game to work. A possible way of doing this would be to include this line in your code before you start checking if the number is too high or low:

```
choice = int(choice)
```

This will throw an error in case the user does not enter an integer number like '1.2' or something which is not a number at all.

Here is an example you can try out:

```
import random

win = False

randomnumber = random.randint(1, 100)

print("I have picked a number between 1 and 100. Try and guess it!")

choice = input("Pick a number\n")

choice = int(choice)

Win = False

if choice == randomnumber:
    print("Good!!")
    Win = True
elif choice > randomnumber:
    print("Too high")
elif choice < randomnumber:
    print("Too Low")
```

For your game to work you will still need to add some form of loop, so that the user can get closer to the right guess with time.